# My application sends data to the COSMOS Database. Do I need to have Internet permission enabled in the Android Manifest?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using such code items as

```
 client = new DocumentClient(new System.Uri(accountURL), accountKey);
 await client.CreateDocumentAsync(collectionLink, deserializedItem);
```

Is anyone aware of if I need to have the internet permission enabled for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the following check boxes for android in order to access cosmos DB.

1. AccessNetworkState
2. Internet